# Ansible: Set variable to file content

Tags: ansible

I'm using the ec2 module with `ansible-playbook` I want to set a variable to the contents of a file. Here's how I'm currently doing it.

1. Var with the filename
2. shell task to `cat` the file
3. use the result of the `cat` to pass to the ec2 module.

Example contents of my playbook.

```yaml
vars:
  amazon_linux_ami: "ami-fb8e9292"
  user_data_file: "base-ami-userdata.sh"

tasks:
  - name: user_data_contents
    shell: 'cat {{ user_data_file }}'
    register: user_data_action
  - name: launch ec2-instance
    local_action:
    ...
    user_data: '{{ user_data_action.stdout }}'
```

I assume there's a much easier way to do this, but I couldn't find it while searching Ansible docs.

Comment: This one worked for me. I did not find how to embed variables in a lookup(pipe) command.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins) in Ansible in order to get the contents of a file on local machine, e.g.

```
user_data: "{{ lookup('file', user_data_file) }}"
```

**Caveat:** This lookup will work with local files, not remote files.

Here's a [complete example from the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins):

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
     contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt') }}"
  tasks:
     - debug: msg="the value of foo.txt is {{ contents }}"
```

Comment: Note that lookup runs locally, while the ``cat`` command in @TesterJeff's example is running on the remote machine.

Comment: For remote lookups check the slurp and fetch modules

Answer (score 43):

You can use the [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html)  module to fetch a file from the remote host: (Thanks to @mlissner for suggesting it)

```
vars:
  amazon_linux_ami: "ami-fb8e9292"
  user_data_file: "base-ami-userdata.sh"
tasks:
- name: Load data
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: "{{ user_data_file }}"
  register: slurped_user_data
- name: Decode data and store as fact # You can skip this if you want to use the right hand side directly...
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    user_data: "{{ slurped_user_data.content | ansible.builtin.b64decode }}"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [fetch module](http://docs.ansible.com/fetch_module.html) to copy files from remote hosts to local, and [lookup module](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html) to read the content of fetched files.

Comment: I'm totally new to ansible, but why not use slurp for this? It seems to work on the remote to pull in the contents of a file.

Answer (score -2):

lookup only works on localhost. If you want to retrieve variables from a variables file you made remotely use include_vars: `{{ varfile }}` . Contents of `{{ varfile }}` should be a dictionary of the form  `{"key":"value"}`, you will find ansible gives you trouble if you include a space after the colon.

Comment: This is nonsense. `include_vars` works locally on the control machine, not with files on the target.