# Ansible: read remote file

Tags: ansible

I generate files with ansible on remote host and after this generation, I would like to read theses files in another task.

I don't find any module to read remote file with ansible (lookup seems only on local host).

Do you know a module like this ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is my use case:

I generate ssh keys and I add it to github. These keys are setting by an object in var files so I loop like this to generate it:

```
    tasks:
  - name: Create ssh key
    user:
      name: "{{sshConfigFile.user}}"
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_file: ".ssh/{{item.value.file}}"
      state: present
    with_dict: "{{sshConfiguration}}"
```

It works very fine but how read these keys to send it to github via the API ?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24003880/1837991

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note that when this question was asked, the following solution was acceptable. Later versions of Ansible may provide a better solution to solve this problem.**

As you said, all lookups are on localhost. But all of them can be done on remote by using `shell` and `register`. Can you tell what exactly you are trying to do? just an example.

```
  - shell: cat "{{remote_file}}"
    register: data

  - shell: ......
    with_xxxx:
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but I can't because I need to loop on another object.

Comment: bad answer, avoid shell and command modules wherever possible (they are not naturally idempotent), you should be using the slurp module .. arguable that because this is a read only op a shell command is acceptable but best to get into the habit of avoiding shell commands where a natural ansible solution exists .. see my answer below for best approach

Answer (score 148):

Either run with the --diff flag (outputs a diff when the destination file changes) ..

```
ansible-playbook --diff server.yaml
```

or [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) it up ..

```
- name: Slurp hosts file
  slurp:
    src: /etc/hosts
  register: slurpfile

- debug: msg="{{ slurpfile['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

Comment: atow i rekon this will one day be top answer

Comment: this is the idomatic solution

Comment: 5 years later I wasn't wrong was I ... I thought I was wrong once but I was mistaken

Answer (score 8):

You can try the ['fetch'](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) module, which will retrieve the key file to a destination path on `localhost`:

```
fetch: 
  src: ".ssh/{{item.value.file}}" 
  dest:"/tmp/ssh_keys/{{item.value.file}}"
  flat: yes
with_dict: "{{sshConfiguration}}"
```

Comment: good answer but slurp is better which avoids creating a tmp file on localhost .. the docs for fetch say that under the hood it uses slurp

Comment: @danday74 You are correct in that using slurp will avoid the temp file. However, if you reread the note for fetch, it states "*When running fetch with `become`, the slurp module will also be used [...]*". In this example, he is not using become

Answer (score 3):

You can register the contents of the file in a variable using the register command. Here is what I would suggest,

```
- name: get contents of file
  command: cat /path/to/file
  register: filename
  become: true # use case specific option

- name: viewing the contents
  debug:
    msg: "{{filename.stdout}}"
```

This will display the contents of the file .

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725536/1837991

Answer (score -8):

By using command module you can read or use that file in another task in remote node.

like

```
-command: cp /tmp/xxx/example.sh /usr/local/yyy
```